# How do I generate an RSA public/private key in .Net, of a specific length?

Tags: .net, encryption

I'm using the RSACryptoServiceProvider to do some asymmetric encryption.

As per MSDN, when you instantiate a new RSACryptoServiceProvider, you get a public/private key pair generated for you that you can use.

Clearly this pair is being generated using some defaults - specifically the length.  I'd like to specify my own length for greater security.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the constructors for RSACryptoServiceProvider takes a KeySize as parameter. Do consult the docs about allowable values though.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0c0sch1.aspx

```
public:
RSACryptoServiceProvider(
    int dwKeySize, // <- wow a size!
    CspParameters^ parameters
)
```